# Both adding and not adding 'typename' to templated static member initialization gives errors

Tags: c++, templates, static, typename

While initializing a templated static member, both adding and not adding 'typename' give errors. I am not sure where I am wrong here. Below is a complete, minimal example:

**myclass.h**

```
template <typename T> class MyClass{
    public:    
        static T G;
};
```

Case 1: **myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h" 

template<typename T> MyClass<T>::G = 25;
```

Output 1:

```
error: need 'typename' before 'MyClass<T>::G' because 'MyClass<T>' is a dependent scope
```

Case 2: **myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h" 

template<typename T> typename MyClass<T>::G = 25;
```

Output 2:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

Could you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing much to say, just:

```
template<typename T> T MyClass<T>::G = 25;
```

You can see it working here [on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b44ebc8731c578b)